# What happens to Bambu printers if they loose wifi connectivity during a print and are unable to recover it?

Tags: bambu

For the current range of Bambu Printers (P1P\X1-Carbon). If you store your files in the cloud and initiate a print through the phone app to the printer using wifi, what happens to the print if the printer loses wifi connectivity for an extended period of time during the printing process and is unable to recover it?

For example, if you are 1 hour into a 5 hour print will it continue to print as normal until the print is complete using a cached copy of the file that it downloaded during that first hour, but without app connectivity.

Or will it simply stop and wait for the user to perform a corrective action.

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your question, the scenario that you pose would be a strong argument **against** using the cloud to print from.

Comment: If the printer simply downloads the entire file before it starts, and then prints it from it's local memory card, the only downside would be the loss of remote monitoring.

Comment: My Creality Cloud box required an SD card to print wirelessly. The box simply downloaded the file to its local memory and then printed it from there. If it lost wireless connectivity during a print it wouldn't even be aware of it and would just continue to print as normal.

Comment: While not answering your question, TeachingTech recently put out a video called [The pros and cons of 3D printer cloud connectivity](https://youtu.be/cP-VrzuJUXc) that you may be interested in.

Comment: Could we please limit things to the specific question, so as to avoid drift.